# Picker not select xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, mvvmcross, picker

I have on a 3-screen Picker, but let's just review one of them first based on the video below.

In my Model view I have.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> DadosPessoa { get; }
private dbo_registro_dado _dado;
        public dbo_registro_dado Dado
        {
            get => _dado;
            set => SetProperty(ref _dado, value);
        }
public AddDadosViewModel(dbo_registro_dado registro)
        {
var contentsPessoa = await App.DadosRepo.GetAllDadosPessoaAsync();
            DadosPessoa.Clear();
            foreach (var d in contentsPessoa)
            {
                DadosPessoa.Add(d.nomePessoa);
            }
Dado = registro;
}
```

In my page xaml

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Dado.pessoa}" ></Label>
<Picker Title="Pessoa" ItemsSource="{Binding DadosPessoa}" SelectedItem="{Binding Dado.pessoa}"  />
```

When I call and screen, at certain times appears selected and at certain times does not appear, see in the videos that I added a Label above the picker only to be sure what information is appearing

it will be because of the data loading delay, what can I do to resolve this?

remembering that the data that fills the picker comes from an internal sqlite base

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OVnc_BMuZ8

Comment: Hello @Ivan, I'm surprised that your code compiles. For what I know, you can't use await in a method that is not marked with the async keyword. And, if AddDadosViewModel is the ctor of your ViewModel, you cannot mark it as async. Are you sure this is the exact code you are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way for a View to wait for an async operation in a ViewModel is to put the call to the async operation in a method of the ViewModel that is marked as async and return a Task:

```
public async Task LoadDataAsync(dbo_registro_dado registro)
{
        var contentsPessoa = await App.DadosRepo.GetAllDadosPessoaAsync();
        DadosPessoa.Clear();
        foreach (var d in contentsPessoa)
        {
            DadosPessoa.Add(d.nomePessoa);
        }
        Dado = registro;
}
```

then from the View call the async method, awaiting for it:

```
await vm.LoadDataAsync(registro);
```

where `vm` is a reference to your ViewModel, `registro` the argument you need to pass.

If you don't instantiate the ViewModel yourself (e.g. you use dependency injection), or if you instantiate it in the constructor of your View (where you cannot use the await keyword) then you can override the OnBindingContextChanged method, like this:

```
protected override async void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        if (BindingContext is YourViewModel vm) {
            await vm.LoadDataAsync();
        }
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
    }
```

Honestly, I doubt that the code you posted can compile, because you try to await for an async operation in a method that is not marked as async. Furthermore, if `AddDadosViewModel` is the constructor of your ViewModel, yon cannot mark it as async, because you cannot mark a constructor as async.

Anyway, try to implement the pattern I explained here, it should work.

Comment: Francesco, worse than my code compiles yes according to the video I posted, I implemented your code suggestion and compiled and ran the app in the emulator, but does not appear the options for selection in the picker, when I click on the picker to select an option is empty.
Here's how I did it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/olzwpc92o7q7m3o/Capturar.JPG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/61kxnrsciep9ush/picker.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Ivan, I tried to write something like your original code and I get a compilation error, as I would have expected, and as you can see [here](https://cp.sync.com/dl/26253cef0#iri5ycm9-d3ntmiwz-fjjujczh-g4vnsizc) . It's very strange that you don't get it.
But, having put aside this mystery -:), does your view model now implements INotifyPropertyChanged correctly? I do not see the setters of DadosPessoa, DadosAtividade and DadosInsumo so I'm asking, just to be sure.

Comment: Hello @Ivan, I think I've found the main problem with your code: when you override the `OnBindingContextChanged` method, you do not call the implementation of the base class, and so the `BindingContext` of your View is not set. This should be why you don't see anything in the picker! Try to add:
`base.OnBindingContextChanged();` at the end of your override.